# Automorphism Groups of Finite Fields

Tags: finite-fields, automorphism-group

In the category [Rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)), if $F_1,F_2,...,F_n$ are finite fields, can the automorphism group $Aut(F_1 \times F_2 \times \cdots \times F_n)$ be  expressed in terms of the automorphism groups $Aut(F_i)$.

Comment: I am considering direct decompositions in $Rng$.  How do you know that every automorphism of $F_1 \times F_2 \times \cdots F_n$ arises in that way?

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, but I don't see how this is obvious. Homomorphisms in Rng need not preserve 1 (since Rng is the category of non-unital, or pseudo, rings). I agree with you that you can take automorphisms of each factor, permute those factors which are isomorphic, and obtain automorphisms of $F_1 \times F_2 \times \cdots \times F_n$. But why should every automorphism arise in this way? For example, if the $F_i$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, then your initial statement is false (consider automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ )

Comment: Of course surjective homomorphisms will preserve identity. But $F_i$ imbeds into $\prod F_i$ in Rng, not at all in Rings with identity. Therefore we can consider the image of $F_i$ under the automorphism, and if this *one* of the $F_j$ for each $i$, then your first comment is correct, and we are done.

Comment: Also, I do think that your first comment is correct. In fact I have a tentative proof of this, but it is relatively long. I am wondering there is a quick n easy way to prove what you say...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}$This is an attempt at a solution, very much in the direction indicated in the comments. I am using the fact that automorphisms preserve annihilators, sizes, etc.

Note that for each $i$, we have that the annihilator of $F_{i}$ in the rng
$$
R = F_1 \times F_2 \times \cdots \times F_n
$$
is of course
$$
 F_1 \times \cdots \times \widehat{F_{i}} \times \cdots \times F_n
$$
(where the hat denotes omission), which is a rng with $2^{n-1}$ idempotents.

Let $G$ be an automorphism, and consider $F_{i}^{g}$, for some $i$. (Sorry, I have the bad habit of writing the action of automorphisms as exponents.)

If $F_{i}^{g}$ is not contained in a single component $F_{j}$, then there are elements of $F_{i}^{g}$ with non-zero components in $F_{h}$ and $F_{k}$, for some $h < k$, so that the annihilator of $F_{i}^{g}$ is contained in
$$
 F_1 \times \cdots \times \widehat{F_{h}} \times \cdots \widehat{F_{k}} \times \cdots\times F_n,
$$
and thus will have at most $2^{n-2}$ idempotents. Thus
$$F_{i}^{g} \subseteq F_{j}$$
for some $j$.

However the annihilator of $F_{i}$ has size $\Size{R}/\Size{F_{i}}$, whereas, $F_{j}$ being a field, the annihilator of $F_{i}^{g}$ has size $\Size{R}/\Size{F_{j}}$. It follows that $F_{i}^{g} = F_{j}$, and thus $F_{i}$ and $F_{j}$ are isomorphic.

It follows that $g$ induces a permutation of the $F_{i}$, which yields a homomorphism from the automorphism group 
$$A = \Aut(F_1 \times F_2 \times \cdots \times F_n)$$
to $S_{n}$. Let $H$ be image of this homomorphism. Clearly $H$ splits as the direct product of smaller symmetric groups, which permute among themselves the $F_{i}$ which are isomorphic. The kernel of this homomorphism is clearly
$$
K = \Aut(F_{1}) \times \cdots \times \Aut(F_{n}),
$$
and then $A$ is the semidirect product of $K$ by $H$.